# Redrawing/refreshing Custom Skin in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, skin

So I created a custom toggle button to include the property currentValue:int

That way I can do the following...

```
<fx:Script>
    protected var currentValue:int = 0;
    protected function changeValue(x:int):void{
        currentValue = x;
    }
</fx:Script>

<MyToggleButton currentValue="{updatedValue}" styleName="MyToggleStyle" click="changeValue(1)" id="first"/>
<MyToggleButton currentValue="{updatedValue}"  styleName="MyToggleStyle" click="changeValue(2)" id="second"/>
```

The idea of this script is to the appearance of the toggle button changed based on the change in currentValue. How would I refresh my toggle button each time so that the style can be updated according to the change in "currentValue"?

P.S. MyToggleStyle will make reference to a Skin class written in mxml which would use getStyle("currentValue") to obtain changes to the currentValue

Answer (score 0):

If the `currentValue` property is only going to affect the skin graphics, and you have a few predefined "looks", then you should create a skin with states. (see `spark.skins.spark.CheckBoxSkin` for a good example.)

in MyToggleButton:

```
public function set currentValue(value:int):void {
   _currentValue = value;
   invalidateSkinState();
}

protected override function getCurrentSkinState():String {
   return _currentValue == 9 ? "someStateName" : "otherState";
}
```

This will invalidate the state of your skin whenever `currentValue` changes and Flex will automatically call `getCurrentSkinState()` to determine the new state of your skin. You can then use `includeIn`, conditional properties, etc. within your skin to determine its look.

If you want to display `currentValue` as text in your skin, you should look into *skin parts.*  These are basically slots that your component defines and the skin then "fills" with a component such as a label. For example, the label on a standard spark button is the `labelDisplay` skin part. The component can set the text on this directly, but it's up to the skin to actually create it.

P.S. You'll also need `[Bindable]` on `currentValue` in your example code.